# Format number to string with custom group and decimal separator without changing precision

Tags: c#, tostring, number-formatting

I would like to format some numbers to strings in C# with custom group/thousands separator and decimal separator. The group and decimal separator can change based on user input so I would like to use a NumberFormatInfo object instead of a hardcoded formatting string. My code below gets the proper separators, but it changes the precision of the number to always be two decimal places, whereas I want to keep the full precision of the number and only show decimal places when needed (so integer values dont have decimal places).

How can I achieve this? I am guessing I need to change the "N" parameter, but change it to what?

```
double n1 = 1234;
double n2 = 1234.5;
double n3 = 1234567.89;
double n4 = 1234.567;

var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

string s1 = n1.ToString("N", nfi); //want "1 234" but I get "1 234,00"
string s2 = n2.ToString("N", nfi); //want "1 234,5" but I get "1 234,50"
string s3 = n3.ToString("N", nfi); //correct output of "1 234 567,89" 
string s4 = n4.ToString("N", nfi); //want " 1 234,567" but I get "1 234,57"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the solution I came up with as an extension method.

```
public static string Format(this double d, NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo)
{
    string s = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int index = s.IndexOf('.');
    int decimalPlaces = index == -1 ? 0 : s.Length - index - 1;
    return d.ToString($"N{decimalPlaces}", numberFormatInfo);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried my solution using `Replace` and `Trim` or `LINQ`? These are all built-in if you look for built-in solutions...

Comment: your solution will fail under many circumstances since you provide ""### ### ###.###" as a parameter and that string is dependent upon the value of the double and how many decimal place digits it has. It also depends on the decimal separator and group separator in the NumberFormatInfo object. For example, your solution will fail with the double value of 0.1234 as it rounds it to three decimal places. Creating a custom version of that string for each number and NumberFormatInfo object is error prone and not practical. My solution always works with any double and any NumberFormatInfo object

Comment: I see... then you may consider using `LINQ` too, since it is a built-in. The `LINQ` solution should be able to handle other solutions you mention.

Comment: Anyway, you got my upvote for the extension. (Haven't tested it yet, but seems to be OK).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

There *is* a workaround using built-in `ToString()` (by using digit placeholder `#`) *and* `Replace` *and/or* `Trim`:

```
double n1 = 1234;
double n2 = 1234.5;
double n3 = 1234567.89;
double n4 = 1234.567;
string s1 = n1.ToString("### ### ###.###").Replace(".",",").Trim();
string s2 = n2.ToString("### ### ###.###").Replace(".", ",").Trim();
string s3 = n3.ToString("### ### ###.###").Replace(".", ",").Trim();
string s4 = n4.ToString("### ### ###.###").Replace(".", ",").Trim();
```

Combining it with numeric format to read `,` as decimal separator *doesn't* work though:

```
double n1 = 1234;
double n2 = 1234.5;
double n3 = 1234567.89;
double n4 = 1234.567;

var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

string s1 = n1.ToString("### ### ###,###", nfi); //doesn't work
string s2 = n2.ToString("### ### ###,###", nfi);
string s3 = n3.ToString("### ### ###,###", nfi);
string s4 = n4.ToString("### ### ###,###", nfi);
```

**Original:**

I guess you cannot use *only* the built-in `ToString()` to get it right. You probably need some `LINQ` tricks to get the result you want:

```
double n1 = 1234;
double n2 = 1234.5;
double n3 = 1234567.89;
double n4 = 1234.567;

var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";

string s1 = new string(n1.ToString("N", nfi).Reverse().SkipWhile(x => x == '0' || x == ',').Reverse().ToArray());
string s2 = new string(n2.ToString("N", nfi).Reverse().SkipWhile(x => x == '0' || x == ',').Reverse().ToArray());
string s3 = new string(n3.ToString("N", nfi).Reverse().SkipWhile(x => x == '0' || x == ',').Reverse().ToArray());
string s4 = new string(n4.ToString("N", nfi).Reverse().SkipWhile(x => x == '0' || x == ',').Reverse().ToArray());
```

There reason is because of the two things as follow:

1. First, `double` is *not* precise. When you input something like `double n = 1234.5`, the actual `double` value stored could be something like  `n = 1234.499999999999998`
2. Second, it is about `ToString()`. It is really used only for formatting. In other words, depends on how you dictate it, it will show something out. For instance, if you give instruction to show the number with 2 significant digits after decimal separator, then it will show the number with exactly 2 significant digits after decimal separator.

Now, putting the two things together *we got a dilemma here*! What you want the program to do is: "Show my as many number of significant digits as it needs to be". However, when you input `double n = 1234.5`, the program will show `1234.499999999999998` instead! But on the other hand, you also do not want to fix the number after decimal separator.

So, I guess you should be using LINQ `SkipWhile` and `Reverse` to do that, not by simple built-in.

Answer (score 0):

//this is the best way for you:

s3 = n3.ToString($"### ##0{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}00");

//or my prefer:

s3 = n3.ToString($"###{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator}##0{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}00");

//I am always using this. nop. it is best and smallest way. :)
//Best Regards. Ersin Kecis.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number of decimal places in NumberFormatInfo and use TrimEnd() to remove additional zeros and seperators.

```
    nfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 15;

    public static string FormatDouble(double d, NumberFormatInfo nfi)
    {
        return d.ToString("N", nfi).TrimEnd('0', ' ', ',', '.');
    }
```